# grunt ngtemplates task 100% cpu

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

The grunt task ngtemplates runs indefinitely (almost an hour and not finished) with 100% cpu utilisation. If i comment this task, then the build finishes.
And the build task with ngtemplates runs and completes OK on another machine.
Any ideas/clues are much appreciated.

Node version: 0.10.29
grunt-cli: v0.1.13
grunt: v0.4.5

```
ngtemplates: {
            app: {
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: ['views/{,*/}*.html', 'views/inbox/{,*/}*.html' , 'scripts/directives/*.html'],
                dest: 'scripts/templates.js',
                options: {
                    usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js', // <~~ This came from the <!-- build:js --> block
                    htmlmin: {
                        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                        removeComments: true, // Only if you don't use comment directives!
                        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Post your Gruntfile.js/task code if you want some help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I really do not know but that should be solved by removing eliminating the line about 73 `.map (this.minify)` from *"node_modules/grunt-angular-templates/task/lib/ compiler.js"*

Comment: If you ever find the clean solution, remember to post it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when running my build with grunt and the ngtemplates task wouldn't complete.

I can confirm that the answer above to comment out line 73 of "node_modules/grunt-angular-templates/task/lib/ compiler.js" does allow the task to complete. However, this is not likely the problem (and you lose out on the minification of the files if you comment that line).

For me, I had an HTML syntax error in one of my HTML files. I discovered this by running my files through [w3's HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/check). After I fixed the syntax error, the ngtemplates task completed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using @isidro-martinez solution you may find the real issue. My problem was an undeteced syntax error on my JS. I've been able to find it thank to **temporarilly** removing the line in the previouse comment:

> I had the same problem, I really do not know but that should be solved by removing eliminating the line about 73 .map (this.minify) from "node_modules/grunt-angular-templates/task/lib/ compiler.js"